# Performance wise which is better - Dataframe Map vs Expression in Polars?

Tags: rust, rust-polars

I am new to polar. I want to create a new column based on multiple columns. I could see that Expression is powerful but for complex logic it is quite difficult to interpret with `case` and `when`.

So I tried the `map` available in `LazyFrame` and it looks like it serves the purpose. However, I am not sure if there will be a performance penality? Or Is there any other simpler method which I dont know of.

Below is my code with `Map`

```
    let df = lf
        .map(
            |df: DataFrame| {
                let a = &df["a"];
                let b = &df["b"];
                let r: Series = a
                    .f32()?
                    .into_iter()
                    .zip(b.f32()?.into_iter())
                    .map(|(Some(a), Some(b))| -> i32 {
                        if a * b == 10.0 {
                            10.0
                        } else if a * b == 20.0 {
                            a.cos();
                        } else {
                            b.cos()
                        }
                    })
                    .collect();
                let df_new = DataFrame::new(vec![df["c"], df[r]])?;
                Ok(df_new)
            },
            None,
            None,
        )
        .select(&[
            a.clone().max().alias("max"),
            b.clone().min().alias("min"),
            r.clone().mean().cast(DataType::Float32).alias("mean"),
        ])
        .collect()?;
```

Compared to the Expression below,

```
    let r = when((a * b).eq(lit::<f32>(10.0)))
        .then(lit::<f32>(10.0))
        .when((a * b).eq(lit::<f32>(20.0)))
        .then(cos(a))
        .otherwise(cos(b));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you map a custom function over a `DataFrame` you are saying trust me optimizer, I know what I am doing. We are not able to do any optimizations anymore.

Besides that, the expression are often executed in parallel. In the `when -> then -> otherwise` expression you wrote, all branches are evaluated in parallel.

```rust
when((a * b).eq(lit::<f32>(10.0)))
        .then(lit::<f32>(10.0))
        .when((a * b).eq(lit::<f32>(20.0)))
        .then(cos(a))
        .otherwise(cos(b));
```

If its faster depend on the use case. I'd say benchmark.

However, you will get used to thinking in expressions and then the expression syntax turns out to be much more consice.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I saw in your GitHub response you mentioned about using chunkedarray for trigonometric operations. How can I use that in expr?

Comment: I think that's better suited to another stackoverflow question. ;)

Comment: Got it. Will create a separate one